# MatLab: How to append 2 arrays with different datatypes to a table?

Tags: arrays, matlab, types

I am trying to create a table with measurement data to write it to a SQL DB later.

Currently I am struggling by appending 2 arrays with different datatypes to one table.

The array for voltage values has the datatype "double" while timestamp is an "int64".

Using array2table works fine except the datatype of both columns of the table is int64.

I managed to define the datatypes of the 2 columns in the table but as soon as I append the arrays my table predefined table is overwritten.

Is there a way to achieve this goal? Thanks in advance!

```
packetData = {'1.2 1573209575861;1.1 1573209575861;1.0 1573209575861;0.9 1573209575861;0.8 1573209575861;', '1.3 1573209575862;1.2 1573209575862;1.1 1573209575862;1.0 1573209575862;0.9 1573209575862;', '1.4 1573209575863;1.3 1573209575863;1.2 1573209575863;1.1 1573209575863;2.0 1573209575863;'};
stringvalues = split(packetData, ";");

dim_stringvalues = size(stringvalues);

i_max = dim_stringvalues(2)
j_max = (dim_stringvalues(3))-1
k_max = ((dim_stringvalues(3))-1)*i_max

k=1;

while k<=k_max
    for i = 1:i_max
        for j = 1:j_max

                datagram_entries(k,1)=stringvalues(1,i,j);
                k=k+1;
        end
    end
end

%Split and create separate arrays
split_voltage_timestamp = split(datagram_entries, " ");
voltage_string = split_voltage_timestamp(:,1)
timestamp_string = split_voltage_timestamp(:,2)

%Convert
voltage = str2double(voltage_string)
timestamp_double = str2double(timestamp_string)
timestamp = int64(timestamp_double)

%Create Table for SQL
tableSize = [length(voltage) 2]  %nx2 Tabelle 

data_array = [voltage timestamp];

table = table('Size', tableSize, 'VariableTypes', {'double', 'int64'}, 'Variablenames', {'Voltage', 'Timestamp'});
table = array2table(data_array, 'Variablenames', {'Voltage', 'Timestamp'});

%% HOW TO APPEND ARRAYS "voltage" and "timestamp" with their correct Datatype?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing the following:

1. Combine `voltage` and `timestamp` into a single array. At this point the variable types must be the same, so you end up with everything as an `int64`.
2. Create a table from your combined array. This is a table of `int64` data because that's what your combined array contains.

Instead, just create a table directly from your variables. Note that `table` is a very bad variable name, because it will shadow the in-built `table` function.

```
tbl = table( voltage, timestamp, 'VariableNames', {'Voltage', 'Timestamp'} );
```

Alternatively, you could initialise the table and add columns one by one:

```
tbl = table();
tbl.Voltage = voltage;
tbl.Timestamp = timestamp;
```